# Security rules : FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm attempting to allow each user read and write their own data using firestore, but I'm getting an insufficient permissions error. I'm not sure why.

I have these rules in place for my firestore. I'm just trying to compare the user's UID (stored in createdBy property) with the user's uid accessible in request.auth.uid

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /bots/{id} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid;
              
       match /order_history/{id} {
         allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And my query that retrieves the data:

```
const orders = await getDocs(query(collectionGroup(db, 'order_history'), orderBy('datetime'), where('createdBy', '==', user.uid)));
    setOrders(orders.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data()
    })))
}
```

Here is an overview of my Firestore organization:
[image]

My front returns `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing a collection group query, which needs a rules of this type:

```
match /{path=**}/order_history/{id} {
  allow read: ...
}
```

That's because a collection group indexes documents at any path in the database, so you also need permission to read that data from any path.

Also see the documentation on [defining security rules for a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups)